# Use start_function from another source file when creating a pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

In my main() method in one source file, I have a call to pthread_create(), as follows:

```
pthread_t pth_chanrecv;
pthread_create(&pth_chanrecv, NULL, chanrecv_run, NULL);
```

"chanrecv_run" is a function in another source file that I have written.
This is the function prototype:

```
void *chanrecv_run(void *arg);
```

The function prototype is in a header file which I have included in the source file containing the main() method.

I'm compiling my program with the following statement:

```
gcc -lpthread -o bin/main2 src/main2.c
```

The chanrecv_run() function is in a file named "chanrecv.c", also in the src folder.

Every time I try and compile it, I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccHxRSTk.o: In function `main':
main2.c:(.text+0x256): undefined reference to `chanrecv_run'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea what's going wrong. I've scoured the web trying to find another instance of someone trying to call a function that was in another file with the pthread_create function and come up completely blank. Is this even possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't pthreads related. Since you've not linked your second .c file containing the `chanrecv_run` function the linker is moaning.

You need:

```
gcc -lpthread -o bin/main2 src/main2.c src/file_with_chanrecv_run_in.c
```

Comment: My initial reason for not doing that was because I had an error crop up with a global variable, but I solved that and now it all works. Thankyou.

Comment: I'm going to mark this one as the answer because it was first (albeit by just 14 seconds).

Answer (score 3):

You need to add it to the compiler call to have it available when the compiler initiates the linking:

```
gcc -Wall -o main2 main2.c chanrecv.c -pthread
```